# Java (1.6) generics wildcard

Tags: java, generics

Consider flowing situation:

```
    class A {

    }

    class B extends A {

    }


    List <? extends A> x = new ArrayList<A>();
    List <? extends A> xx = new ArrayList<B>();
```

both 'x' and 'xx' are legal declarations in Java 6 and Java 7 (I know that in Java 7 you can also substitute the parameterized type of the constructor with an empty set of type parameters (<>). However, I wonder, what is the difference between 'x' and 'xx' in Java 6?

Answer (score 6):

The way you wrote it, there is no difference.

At compile-time, both have the same type; namely, a `List<>` of some unknown type that extends `A`.
This is why you can't add anything to either list – you have no idea whether it's actually a `List<B>` or a `List<C>` or of some other type.

At runtime, they also have the same type; namely, `List`.  Due to type erasure, the type parameter doesn't exist at runtime.

Because you don't save any more strongly-typed references to it, no-one can tell that one of the lists is actually a `List<B>`.

The point of these wildcards is for functions.
You can make a function that takes a `List<? extends A>`, then pass it a `List<B>` or a `List<C>`, and the calling code can keep using the original list with its original type.

Comment: I know that there is no type parameter at runtime, but your answer assumes that in version 6 Java engineers kept redundant parametrized type without any reason. I wouldn't love to think that they just didn't noticed this ))))

Comment: @whiteErru: I'm not sure what you mean.  The type parameters exist, and the compiler must keep track of them.  The actual type parameters (`List<B>`) aren't visible anywhere, so the compiler doesn't need to keep track of them.

Comment: At runtime (JVM) `List <? extends A> x = new ArrayList<A>();` becomes `List x = new ArrayList();`. This is clear. I don't understand if
`List <? extends A> x = new ArrayList<A>();`
`List <? extends A> x = new ArrayList<B>();`
and
`List <? extends A> x = new ArrayList<>();`
are technically the same, why Java 6 allows to declare type parameter in object creation?

Comment: Because the type is not always known from the usage of the expression.  eg, `new ArrayList<X>().someMethod()`, or `Collections.sort(new ArrayList<X>())`

Answer (score 1):

no difference. it all boils down to two lists of objects. You are just trying to coax the compiler to lend you a helping hand, as it's quite clever and could help you catch bad usage. You tell it that as long as the type in the List is-a A, all is fine. The compiler can then help highlighting any problems.